# Filter a collection by multiple attributes provided with a map

Tags: filter, clojure

I have a collection that I want to filter. The filter is done using a map where the key is the attribute in a collection item, and the value is what the collection items should match. Example:

```
(let [filters {:name "test"
               :type "new"}
      collection [{:name "testable"  :type "old"}
                  {:name "shoudwork" :type "new"}
                  {:name "testable"  :type "new"}]])
```

Right now, I have built my filter function to only take a single attribute and value. I want to expand it to actually be able to take a filter `hashmap`.

This is what my current filter looks like:

```
(filter #(re-find (re-pattern "test") (string/lower-case (% :name))) collection)
```

In other words, I want the `filter` to not take `"test`" hardcoded, but it should be the value from the `filters` let binding, and the `(% :name)` to not be hardcoded to `:name`, but be the key from `filters` let binding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a function that returns the filtering function for a single [key expected-value]:

```
(defn regex-value [[k expected-rex]]
  (fn [c] (re-find (re-pattern expected-rex) 
                   (clojure.string/lower-case (get c k)))))
```

Create a function that will create the compounded filtering condition:

```
(defn build-filter [filters]
  (apply every-pred (map regex-value filters)))
```

Use it:

```
(let [filters {:name "test"
               :type "new"}
      collection [{:name "testable"  :type "old"}
                  {:name "shoudwork" :type "new"}
                  {:name "testable"  :type "new"}]]
  (filter (build-filter filters) collection))
```

Comment: I really like this one because it uses `every-pred`. I tried incorporating that in my own solution, but failed.

Answer (score 3):

you can also use transducers:

```
;; first you create a filtering step factory for transduction:
(defn make-filter [[k v]]
  (filter #(re-find (re-pattern v)
                    (clojure.string/lower-case (k %)))))

;; and then transform the collection:
(let [filters {:name "test"
               :type "new"}
      collection [{:name "testable"  :type "old"}
                  {:name "shoudwork" :type "new"}
                  {:name "testable"  :type "new"}]]
  (sequence (reduce comp (map make-filter filters)) collection))
```